# Как прописать ссылку в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите как прописать ссылку в `htaccess`.
не переключается постраничный вывод из файла , в браузере выводится ссылка, а на странице не переключается.
нужно чтоб выглядело вот так `site.ru/blog.html?page=3`

так работает при переходе по страницам

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

а так не переключает постранично из файла

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?alias?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ссылку вообще некорректно указываете. В ссылке все что после вопроса - считается GET параметрами, а у вас тут 2 знака вопроса. Несколько параметров указываются как `index.php?alias=some_value&page=$1` т.е. последующие через символ &

Comment: Спасибо сделал так RewriteRule ^blog&page=([0-9]*)$ index.php?alias=blog&page=$1 [L]  работает сылка так blog&page=1

Comment: Хотелось бы чтоб blog.html?page=1   как справиться с этим?